# Numerical inversion involved confluent hypergeometric (1F1) (or Kummer function)

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration, numerical-analysis-of-pde

**Edit: The question is solved** !! **The code is actually correct. There is not error in the codes. I miss-used it**. Thank you for your attention : )

This problem arises when I tried to compute the valua of [Asian call otions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option) using Inverse Laplace transform method.

Let $r=\mu = 0.15;
\sigma = 0.20;
T = 1;
S_0 = 100;
K = 95;$

Let $\nu:=\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}-1$

and  $\boxed{\eta \equiv\eta(\alpha)}:=-\frac{\nu}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\nu^2+\frac{8\alpha}{\sigma^2}}$.

Define $F$ as follows:
$$ 
F(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\Gamma(\eta+2\mu/\sigma^2)}{\Gamma(2\eta +2\mu/\sigma^2)} \int_K^{\infty}\left(\frac{2S_0}{y\sigma^2}\right)^{\eta}M(\eta, 2\eta+\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}, -\frac{2S_0}{y\sigma^2}) \, dy
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function
and $M$ is the a confluent hypergeometric function

($M$ is the `Hypergeometric1F1` function in Mathematica).

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $F(\alpha)$ NUMERICALLY
$$V(t)=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma- iz}^{\gamma +iz} e^{t\alpha}F(\alpha)d \alpha $$
at $t=1$.

Note that if we let $b=\left(\frac{2S_0}{\sigma^2}\right)$, and $z=b/y$
then we have
$$ 
F(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \left(\frac{2S_0}{\sigma^2}\right)\frac{\Gamma(\eta+2\mu/\sigma^2)}{\Gamma(2\eta +2\mu/\sigma^2)} \int_0^{\frac{b}{K}}z^{\eta-2}M(\eta, 2\eta+\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}, -z) \, dz
$$

So using [the package written by Prof. Valko](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4738/) I write a mathematica program to compute it. Please see the Mathematica code here

> In[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option):= Clear["Global`*"]

(*The program used to find the Inverse Laplace transform numerically*)

```
GWR[F_, t_, M_: 32, precin_: 0] := Module[
  {M1, G0, Gm, Gp, best, expr, \[Tau] = Log[2]/t, Fi, broken, 
prec},
  If[precin <= 0, prec = 21 M/10, prec = precin];
  If[prec <= $MachinePrecision, prec = $MachinePrecision];
  broken = False;
  If[Precision[\[Tau]] < prec, \[Tau] = 
SetPrecision[\[Tau], prec]];
  Do[Fi[i] = N[F[i \[Tau]], prec], {i, 1, 2 M}];
  M1 = M;
  Do[
     G0[n - 1] = \[Tau] (2 n)!/(n! (n - 1)!) Sum[
              Binomial[n, i] (-1)^i  Fi[n + i], {i, 0, n}];
     If[Not[NumberQ[G0[n - 1]]], M1 = n - 1; G0[n - 1] =.; 
Break[]];
     , {n, 1, M}];
  Do[Gm[n] = 0, {n, 0, M1}];
  best = G0[M1 - 1];

  Do[
     Do[
        expr = G0[n + 1] - G0[n];

If[Or[Not[NumberQ[expr]], expr == 0], broken = True; Break[]];
        expr = Gm[n + 1] + (k + 1)/expr;
        Gp[n] = expr;
        If[OddQ[k],
           If[n == M1 - 2 - k, best = expr]
           ];
        , {n, M1 - 2 - k, 0, -1}];
     If[broken, Break[]];
     Do[Gm[n] = G0[n]; G0[n] = Gp[n], {n, 0, M1 - k}];
     , {k, 0, M1 - 2}];
  best
  ]


(*Model parameters*)
mu = 0.15;
sigma = 0.20;
S0 = 100;
K = 95;
T = 1;

 eq = z^(nu - 2)*Hypergeometric1F1[nu, 2*nu + 2*mu/sigma^2, -z];
 int = Integrate[eq, {z, 0.001, 2*S0/(K*sigma^2)}, 
GenerateConditions -> False]*(2*
 S0/sigma^2)*(Gamma[nu + 2*mu/sigma^2]/Gamma[2*nu + 2*mu/sigma^2]);
int2[alpha_] := 
        int /. nu -> (-vu/2 + Sqrt[vu^2 + 8*alpha/sigma^2]/2) /. 
        vu -> (2*mu/sigma^2 - 1);

 F[alpha_] := F[alpha] = int2[alpha]/alpha;
 GWR[F, 1]
 TimeUsed[] (*Time used to compute the value*)
 Out[12]= 13.4836
 Out[13]= 2.184
```

Before I ask my question, I would like to make a remark that 
the routine  : **GWR has  been tested with different functions and it gives correct answers up to 15 decimal places for those tested functions **

However, when I tested with $F$, it gives me a wrong answer:

- when K=95, it gives me 13.4836. The *correct anwer* is 15.643.
- when K=105, it gives me 7.94016. The *correct answer* is : 3.560

**So here is my question:**
is there any thing which is bad for the function $F(\alpha)$ that I don't know? If there is such a bad singulariy, how to remove it.

Thank you so much for your time . I truly appreciate it.

**Edit: The question is solved** !! **The code is actually correct. There is not error in the codes. I miss-used it**. Thank you for your attention : )

Comment: if this question was based on some programming error that you have resolved yourself, you might want to delete it (or in any case, make it clear that there is nothing left for MO users to do)

Comment: Interestingly, the Wolfram Language has inverse functions for a ratio of $\,_0\text F_1$ functions and a special case of $\,_1\text F_1$